# My client is trying to connect their Meraki to our GCP VPN with no luck

Tags: vpn

He confirms the key is correct but we get no packets received.

Here is the log

```
2021-09-02T20:23:11.572410766Z creating acquire job for policy with reqid {1} D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.572566353Z initiating IKE_SA vpn_23.31.252.118[3835] to 23.31.252.118 I 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.577250693Z generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ] D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.578074562Z sending packet: from 35.230.187.120[500] to 23.31.252.118[500] (884 bytes) D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.702791357Z received packet: from 23.31.252.118[500] to 35.230.187.120[500] (462 bytes) D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.703154392Z parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(MULT_AUTH) ] D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.707926435Z remote host is behind NAT D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.707974668Z authentication of '35.230.187.120' (myself) with pre-shared key D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.708035841Z establishing CHILD_SA vpn_23.31.252.118{1} I 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.708143521Z generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(MULT_AUTH) N(EAP_ONLY) ] D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.708650645Z sending packet: from 35.230.187.120[4500] to 23.31.252.118[4500] (332 bytes) D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.737659144Z received packet: from 23.31.252.118[4500] to 35.230.187.120[4500] (76 bytes) D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.737755638Z parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ] D 
2021-09-02T20:23:11.737764927Z received AUTHENTICATION_FAILED notify error D 
  undefined
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And please take the [tour]. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions. You might be looking for [sf].

Answer (score 0):

As per the log, the other side of the GCP tunnel us behind of a NAT.

Please check this information about [On-premises gateways behind NAT](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/support/troubleshooting#gateways_behind_nat)